# Java relative path works differently in different projects with the same code

Tags: java, windows, maven, maven-plugin

I'm not sure if this is a Windows issue or a java issue.  Here is the scenario

I've got a maven project that uses a maven plugin project to build some of its code.  Long story short, its looking for a file in the root directory C:/ because the user.dir is giving the wrong result.

I created 2 different Windows accounts, one is a network domain and the other is local account.  When i do a build using the plugin on the windows local account, it works peachy keen.  However, when i do a build on the network account, it fails because of the user.dir.

Windows domain account returns

```
USer dir i s C:\
```

Windows local account

```
USer dir i s C:\workspace\...correct path
```

With the follwing code.

```
System.out.println("USer dir is" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

I've also tried adding that code in the same project folder on the windows domain account and it finds the path correctly. (Just creating a test class not using maven or the plugin project).

Does anyone know any maven settings that would mess up the user.dir or what a possible explanation could be?

I looked into the permissions of the folders
Right click file -> Properties -> Security -> (Had to create myself as a user) -> Permissions.
In the column inherited from, is marked as  whereas the other accounts inherit from the C:/ drive.

I've set myself as admin and allowed myself full permissions.   I'm to the point of not knowing if its Windows, Java or Maven is causing the problem and would really appreciate any suggestions, pointers, anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the fault of the way you are launching maven.

You can try launching maven with,

```
mvn -Duser.dir=thecorrectpath
```

To set user.dir manually.

Comment: Hello sbridges,   Thank you for your response.  Turns out that a maven plugin that i was using was using java CommandProcessor which was invoking the same thing as the standard cmd.  I had previously set autorun in /HKEY_LOCAL_USER/MICROSOFT/COMMANDPROCESSOR/AUTORUN to pushd C:/  to run straight from my C: directory.  I guess in order for it to work successfully, it shouldn't be forced which allows it to run from my current directory.